# How to allow multiple uninstallers to work independently in same directory?

Tags: install4j

We make many different installers for different products and have them all install into the same directory. Each product has his uninstaller. Because of this, the all uninstallers will have the functionality of the last product installed into this directory.
Is it possible to keep multiple uninstallers and each one to work independently? Each uninstaller has a custom name but their functionality is from the last product installed into directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each product needs its own installation directory. If you have a common parent directory for multiple installers, you can set the actual installation directory to a sub-directory.

To install files to the parent directory, you can define an external root `${installer:parentDirectory}` in the distribution tree and add a "Set a variable" action before the "Install files" action that sets `parentDirectory` to `context.getInstallationDirectory().getParent()`.

Comment: This is one of requirements - to allow installation in same directory, not sub-directory because the products have some common components and folders. I thinks sth that can help me is to rename the .install4j folder with sth custom named. But i didn't find out how can i rename .install4j folder.

Comment: It is not possible to rename the .install4j directory. With the above scheme the actual installation directory can just hold the .install4j directory and the actual installation all goes to the same parent directory.